# Windows Update 2004 - Search box and start menu open simultaneously

Tags: windows-10, updates

I have updated my Windows machine to the newest version 2004 to get WSL 2. Everything is working fine except for one thing:

When I hit the windows button which is supposed to open the start menu, it opens BOTH the start menu AND the Search box.

I have searched high and low but couldn't find this error documented anywhere. 
Has anybody an idea how I can rectify this behaviour manually (like via registry or anything like that) or has somebody had the same error and found a solution.

Merci in advance

A

Comment: Windows Key does open just the Start Menu in Windows 10 V2004.  See if DISM and SFC correct this issue. Open an Admin Command Prompt and run (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth and then (2) SFC /SCANNOW   . Restart when complete and test.

Comment: Ive tried it, but to no avail. merci anyway

Comment: If the usual steps do not work, then you now should do a Windows 10 Repair Install using the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: yes, I thought so myself, just downloading it ...

Comment: Please let us know if the repair helps here.

Comment: Hi John, no it didnt work, the issue remains. I thought maybe one can do some registry hack or something like that

Comment: You may have to reinstall Windows at this point as I am not sure what has gone wrong. What you have is not normal.

Comment: I did reinstall windows @john , its just the messy windows update, other guys have the same error, guess I have to wait until windows is fixing this bug

Comment: There would appear to be some legacy or some software causing compliance issues. I have 3 machines here: 2 Windows 10 2004 production and 1 Insider advanced Windows 10 2004 H2 not causing this issue.

Comment: Also, be sure to update all your drivers, particularly Video and any related drivers.

Comment: ok, merci @john I will try to manually update the drivers

Comment: nothing has changed, all Drivers are up to date. So I wait for Microsoft to clean up its mess ...

Comment: I met the same problem. My previous Windows 10 on the same PC didn't have it. That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

well, found the answer:

https://www.askvg.com/fix-start-menu-not-working-in-windows-10-may-2020-update-version-2004/

Bug caused by 'ImmersiveSearch' registry tweak which produces a floating search window which won't work anymore.

Do the following in Regedit:

Delete

"ImmersiveSearch"=dword:00000001

under

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search]

and

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Flighting\Override]

with entries
"ImmersiveSearchFull"=dword:00000001
"CenterScreenRoundedCornerRadius"=dword:00000009